# ReactJS sharing contexts

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to learn ReactJS and I want to share some data between different parts of my app, specifically whether a user is logged in: my research seems to suggest that a Context is the best way to do this. However I appear to have created two separate contexts, rather than one shared one. The sample project I have created is at https://6nr8vj.csb.app/ - the source project is at https://codesandbox.io/s/6nr8vj.

There are two ways to log in, one from the dropdown menu and the other from the home page, and both the dropdown and the home page have text to show whether they think the user is logged in. I would like these two to share a common context, ie if I log in using one then the other is also updated: however they appear to act independently.

Can anyone shed any light on this, and hopefully let me know what I need to do to make the context shared?

Many thanks,

Graeme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of having a context is to wrap *all* the components needing to share the same data in the *same* context.

Instead of placing a context around `<Home />` and one around `<Navbar />`, place one around `<App />`.

Now all the descendants of App, no matter how deep, get the same instance from `useContext(authContext)`.

See it working: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-cherry-8qgpk4

Also, you don't need a state controlling the menu items. All you need is:

```
const menuItems = authenticated ? authMenuItems : unauthMenuItems
```

Now they'll change accordingly based on the current value of `authenticated`, you no longer need to set them yourself.

---

Last but not least, it is typical to handle the necessary state of the context inside it and provide the initial value(s) via props passed to the provider component. In your case, it would be something like this:

```
import * as React from 'react'

const AuthContext = React.createContext({})

export const useAuthContext = () => React.useContext(AuthContext)

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = React.useState(props.authenticated)
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        authenticated,
        setAuthenticated
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Now import `AuthContextProvider` in your app or tests and pass the appropriate initial value to `authenticated`.
And extract the current value or the setter function from `useAuthContext()` (without needing to import and pass the context every time, as argument).

Comment: Thanks, tao - much appreciated. I thought it would be something like that: I just couldn't figure it out due to my unfamiliarity with React. Thanks for the tip about the menu items, too!